# establish ssh connection and execute command remotely

Tags: linux, bash, ssh

I want to establish connection using ssh, remotely and execute a command.

Eg :

```
var=ntpcz
[host1]$ssh host2 "/oracle/remote/xyz.sh $var"
connection to host2 closed.
```

In the above example it is executing `xyz.sh` command in host2 but it is getting disconnected from host2.
But what I am looking is it should establish a connection to host2 upon executing the xyz.sh script.

Is it possible to do so?

I have seen this post similar to my question 28360288 in this forum, but that is not resolving my issue

Comment: Without the quotes, I think (or around each part of the command separately)

Comment: For debugging, you can also increase verbosity with `-vv` or `-vvv` or similar